# Calling function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I use an HTML `button` to run a function called `start_KEMT` in my `recorder.js` script.

```js
var recording = false;
    var button = document.getElementById('button');

    function start_KEMT() {
       if(!recording)
       {
          init();
          toggleRecording(button);
      }
      toggleRecording(button);
      recording = !recording;
    }


      function toggleRecording(button) {
        var run = parseInt(button.getAttribute('data-run')); 
        
        if(run === 1) {
          recorder && recorder.stop();
          recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
            uploadAudioFromBlob(blob);
          });
          __log('Recording is stopped');
          button.setAttribute('data-run', 0);
          
        } 
          recorder && recorder.clear();
          recorder && recorder.record();
          __log('Speak');
          button.setAttribute('data-run', 1);
        }
      }
      ......
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="button" onclick="start_KEMT(this)" data-run="0"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;</button>
```

After clicking on the button the `init()` function runs. There is problem with `toggleRecording(button)`. I think that problem is because of the `button` element. After clicking on the button there is also an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Can you please give me an whole example how to modify it? I am really new to JS. I am just trying to modify this script. It wasn't created by me.

Comment: Pass parameter to `start_KEMT(button)` instead of `start_KEMT()`.

Comment: function start_KEMT(button) {
   if(!recording)
   {
      init();
      toggleRecording(button);
  }
  toggleRecording(button);
  recording = !recording;
}

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `button` in the HTML - `onclick="start_KEMT(this)"`. `this` is button element. But you are not defining it in the function.

Change your function `start_KEMT` to

```
function start_KEMT(button) {
   if(!recording)
   {
      init();
      toggleRecording(button);
  }
  toggleRecording(button);
  recording = !recording;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `recorder.js` ,change your function signature from `start_KEMT()` to `start_KEMT(**button**)` .That will solve your problem , as it (i.e. button variable) is undefined right now.